# Proof of unique solution of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently learning more about PDE's and have the following exercise: Consider the PDE
$$
-\Delta u+ \ln u=f\quad \text{in}\ \Omega,\\ 
u=u_d\quad \text{on}\ \partial\Omega
$$
where $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ is nonnegative and $u_d\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ with $u_d\geq \varepsilon>0$ a.e. in $\Omega$. I'm now trying to prove that there exists a unique positive solution $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ for this PDE.

My problems are with showing the existence of a solution. I was thinking about formulating the weak notion of this problem, i.e. showing that there exist a unique positive $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, s. th.
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla \varphi+\ln(u)\cdot \varphi=\int_\Omega f\varphi+\int_{\partial\Omega}u_d\varphi
$$
for alle $\varphi$. For uniqueness I just assume that there exist two solutions $u_1,u_2$ and define $w=u_1-u_2$. Then $w$ suffices the equality
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla w\cdot \nabla \varphi+\ln(\frac{u_1}{u_2})\varphi=0.
$$
Choosing now $\varphi=u_1-u_2$, we get
$$
\Vert\nabla w\Vert_2^2+\int_\Omega ln(\frac{u_1}{u_2})(u_1-u_2)=0
$$
From that it immediately follows that $u_1=u_2$.

But then I have no idea how to continue to show the existence. Does anybody have an idea or an alternative approach? That would be so helpfull.